# Android Repo init failed

Tags: android, git, ubuntu, repository, android-source

I think i follow instruction from this site very carefully

http://source.android.com/source/downloading.html

but when i try this

```
repo init -u https://android.googlesource.com/platform/manifest
```

i got the following error.

```
 repo init -u https://android.googlesource.com/platform/manifest -b froyo 
/root/bin/repo: line 1: syntax error near unexpected token `newline' 
/root/bin/repo: line 1: `<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>'enter code here`
```

I tried several times but no luck from the very begining. What happened?

Comment: The grandstanding of the people who took the liberty to close this question is just incredible and unfortunately all too common on SO. It is perfectly clear what is being asked: me and another commenter had no problem understanding the question.

Comment: voted to reopen: this question and answer are useful.

Comment: This question should be opened. The question is clear and precise. Answer is also clear.

Comment: I had the same problem. The instruction curl https://dl-ssl.google.com/dl/googlesource/git-repo/repo > ~/bin/repo , might fail. In that case the repo command might be an html page with 'resource not found'. Just see what is in the repo file (it sould be a python script, not an HTML page vi \~bin\repo ). If this is not the python script see if you can resolve the curl download request first.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Check your `repo` file.

Sometimes the server would return a  "server loading too high" page instead of giving you the `repo` script. In this case, you have to download your `repo` file again.

Alternativly, you can get the source of `repo` from git:

```
git clone https://android.googlesource.com/tools/repo
```

Comment: Yes, do check your repo file. It is a python script, not an HTML or XML file, so if you are getting an error message that quotes bits of HTML or XML when trying to use repo, odds are when you tried to fetch the repo script in the first place the server responded with a 301 or 404 error message, hence the XML/HTML. The instructions on http://source.android.com/ should have the correct location (it changes often; Google is unfortunately not a class act but a bit messy).