# Android repo init failed when trying to download souce-code

Tags: android, repository

I followed some guide how to download the source code of Android.

http://omappedia.org/wiki/Android_Getting_Started#Accessing_Source_Code
and
http://source.android.com/source/downloading.html

I'm able to download repo and make it executable. But after that I use this command:

`repo init -u https://android.googlesource.com/platform/manifest`

or

`repo init -u git://git.omapzoom.org/platform/omapmanifest.git -b froyo`

But both commands give the following error:

> Fatal: branch 'stable' has not been signed

Anyone knows how to fix this, so I can download the source code?

I already tried to re-install repo. Suggested on this link [Android Repo init failed](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6234666/android-repo-init-failed)

I'm behind a proxy, but I used commands to let the proxy work.

Answer (score 1):

Solved editing REPO_URL definition in repo file, changing https to http.

Answer (score 1):

Not only change REPO_URL definition in repo file from https to http, you also need to change in your command. Example:

```
repo init -u http://android.googlesource.com/platform/manifest
```

If you still get error, try latest repo tool by use the command bellow

```
repo init -u http://android.googlesource.com/platform/manifest --repo-url=https://android.googlesource.com/tools/repo
```

or

```
repo init -u http://android.googlesource.com/platform/manifest --repo-url=http://android.googlesource.com/tools/repo
```